# Send email to users with same Taxonomy term selection in node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, emails

I have a node type "Question" which has a term reference field called "Question about". Now I'm trying to create a rule to send emails when a new "Question" is created to the users who have the same term reference. Both term reference fields are connected to the same vocabulary (Question category).

So it looks like this:

EVENT: On new content (question) with a term reference
CONDITION: term reference field is same in "Question" and "User"
ACTION: email to users with the same term reference field called "Specialist in".

Can php be a solution? Please help :)